# PHP Notice: Error: Could not load config default - OC 3.0.3.9

Tags: opencart

```
    <?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://develop.ladimonty.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://develop.ladimonty.com/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/ladimont/develop.ladimonty.com/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/ladimont/develop.ladimonty.com/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/ladimont/develop.ladimonty.com/image/');
define('DIR_STORAGE', '/home/ladimont/develop.ladimonty.com/storage/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', DIR_APPLICATION . '/home/ladimont/develop.ladimonty.com/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', DIR_APPLICATION . '/home/ladimont/develop.ladimonty.com/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', DIR_SYSTEM . '/home/ladimont/develop.ladimonty.com/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', DIR_STORAGE . '/home/ladimont/develop.ladimonty.com/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . '/home/ladimont/develop.ladimonty.com/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', DIR_STORAGE . '/home/ladimont/develop.ladimonty.com/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', DIR_STORAGE . '/home/ladimont/develop.ladimonty.com/modification/');
define('DIR_SESSION', DIR_STORAGE . '/home/ladimont/develop.ladimonty.com/session/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . '/home/ladimont/develop.ladimonty.com/upload/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'lsales');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

Getting the following error:

> [01-Feb-2024 05:25:21 UTC] PHP Notice:  Error: Could not load config default! in /home/ladimont/develop.ladimonty.com/system/library/config.php on line 63

Any Valuable suggestions?

Comment: What is line #63?

Comment: Error in System/Library/Config.php

Comment: Does this file exist in your project? : `system/library/config.php`